# jquery optgroup selection according to label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am getting value dynamically which is my label in optgroup.  now using jquery   i want to show only that optgroup which matches with my dynamic value.

```
<select class="form-select"  id="test">
  <option value="_none">- None -</option>
     <optgroup label="Personal / Web Conferencing">
       <option value="257"> 1 </option>
       <option value="374"> dd </option>
       <option value="332"></option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Personanew">
       <option value="257"> 1 </option>
       <option value="374"> dd </option>
       <option value="332"></option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Personalsss">
       <option value="257"> 1 </option>
       <option value="374"> dd </option>
       <option value="332"></option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Personalsss">
       <option value="257"> 1 </option>
       <option value="374"> dd </option>
       <option value="332"></option>
    </optgroup>
 </select>
```

How to do this using jquery. i dnt have any idea about this . how to play with optgroup 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that if you have a `input type` either `hidden` or `text`, `i used hidden` in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/79XUA/**

on default i hid them with css.

```
optgroup{display:none;} // no optgroup initially
```

then using jquery depending on the value of `hidden text input` i showed it.

```
$('select optgroup[label="'+$('#opt').val()+'"]').show();
//---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------depending on hidden input value
//------------------------------------------------showed corresponding optgroup
```

you can checkout the fiddle above.

Comment: i want to show only  all options with particular optgroup haveing label matched with my dyamic value

Comment: and where you are having your `dynamic value`?

Comment: like u take in hidden field.. in ur output all optgropus with options are showing.. i want to show only select optgroup woth their options

Comment: so this means you just want to render corresponding markup not all optgroups.